# How to Cancel Call to Chat-GPT with Next.js OpenAI Example

Tags: reactjs, next.js, openai-api

In the Next.js example: https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/solutions/ai-chatgpt, there is a while loop that iterates over a stream to fetch tokens back from OpenAI's ChatGPT. I want to add a cancel button to stop the stream while it is outputting.

I read the docs here: https://sdk.vercel.ai/docs/concepts/backpressure-and-cancellation and I believe I should be able to just stop the do while loop and that should be enough.

I think the React Component Lifecycle is messing with me because even when I create a "cancelled" state, and put it in the loop like this:

```
while (!done && !cancelled) {
  const { value, done: doneReading } = await reader.read();
  done = doneReading;
  const chunkValue = decoder.decode(value);
  ...
```

And then verify I have my cancelled state set by rendering it, the while loop still does not stop processing.

How can I stop the while loop from running in a react component like in the Next example I referenced above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop a loop from running, use a mutable reference or object property to keep track of whether the operation has been canceled, and check this value in each iteration of the loop

```
 let cancelObject = { cancelled: false };  //  track whether operation has been cancelled

const fetchData = async () => {
    const reader = yourStream.getReader();
    let { value, done } = await reader.read();
    const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
    let completeMessage = '';
    
    while (!done && !cancelObject.cancelled) {
      const chunkValue = decoder.decode(value);
      completeMessage += chunkValue;
      
      let result = await reader.read();
      value = result.value;
      done = result.done;
    }

    //  if not cancelled
    if (!cancelObject.cancelled) {
      console.log(completeMessage);
    }
};

const cancel = () => {
  cancelObject.cancelled = true;  // Trigger cancellation
};

fetchData();
```

Sometime later you can  Call the `cancel` function to stop the while loop

```
cancel();
```